# AMP for cyrillic TLD domain

Tags: amp-html

When I turn on AMP on WordPress website in Google search web page I see that Cyrillic top-level domain display in Latin transcription. How I could fix it? I want that AMP webpage display Cyrillic top-level domain as on normal webpage:

[image: Normal webpage]
[image: AMP]